# Problem on VNM utility

Tags: microeconomics, utility, uncertainty

Preferences are represented by the function $u(w) = √w$ .

An investor has 5000 dollars that can be invested. Investing $X ∈ [0,5000]$ he will receive $r_H X$ in addition to W with probability $P$ and will lose $r_L X$ with probability $(1-P)$. Assume that $1>r_i>0$ where $i=H,L$.

If the optimal size of investment is strictly positive and less than 5000 dollars, what would be the optimal amount of investment? (as a function of $r_H, r_L, P$).

Do you have any idea on solving this problem?
i've tried to solve an inequality like $EU(w) ≥ U(5000)$. Got something weird like $Y≤ \frac {P^2 *5000(r_H +1) +5000*(1-P)^2(1-r_L)-100}{2P^2 - 2P+1}$ (Y is an amount investing)

Comment: Hint: Determine the wealth levels in the two states, write down the expected utility, and then maximize it with respect to $X$.

Comment: You should also specify, what W is.